# How to create setup file in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wix

i'm coding a small project, it is my homework, it's about school. I code in visual studio 2012 and it doesn't support create setup file. I use Wix to create setup file but it doesn't include my database. when i create successful setup file and click setup file to setup it just create 1 file .exe like the file in ../Debug/. I don't know how to create setup file that include my database. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is your database a CE database (that is, one which is in a file)?

Comment: (1) What do you want to accomplish? (2) What have you tried, in detail (including WiX file)? (3) What was the result of your attempt and what was the expected result?

Comment: i use Sqlserver to create database. I detached to .mdf file. I want when i create setup file with Wix it also include that .mdf file

Comment: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_votive_project.htm
I read above article and do like he said

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to create an windows installer which includes your database (if compact edition or any other non-server database) and your executable program (the one which is in /Debug folder). You will have to read the documentation to know how to include files in installer.

Answer (score 1):

> I code in visual studio 2012 and it doesn't support create setup file.

Guess waht - THANK HEAVEN. THose Projects sucked o start with and did not pass validations.

> I use Wix to create setup file but it doesn't include my database

No. YOU do not include your database. WIX does not care.

> I don't know how to create setup file that include my database. Can anybody help me?

Yes. WIX has documentation. Point is, what database. SQL Server - make another burn proejct, preinstall SQL Server if needed. Then use the SQL mechanisms in WIX (for example like http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_sqldatabase.htm) to create the database.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to create a setup file is [Excelsior Installer](http://installer.excelsior-usa.com/en/).
It is a free tool and probably easier than Wix.
You can define which files should be included in your installation.